# Slurm sinfo format

Tags: slurm

When I use "sinfo" in slurm, I see an asterik near one of the partition (like: RUNNING-CLUSTER*).

The partition look well and all nodes under it are idle.

When I run a simple script with "sleep 300" for example, I can see the jobs in the queue (using "squeue") but they run for a few seconds and end. No error message (I can see in the log that they failed. No more info there).

Any idea what the asterisk is for?
Couldn't find it in the manual.

Thanks.

Comment: @VermillionAzure - "Slurm is an open-source workload manager designed for Linux clusters of all sizes. It provides three key functions. ". From here:  [http://slurm.schedmd.com/]

Comment: IMHO, this question would better fit [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), but is rather off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

The "*" following the partition name indicates that this is the default partition for submitted jobs. [LLNL](https://computing.llnl.gov) provides documentation that directly supports my findings:

[LLNL Documentation](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/quickstart.html)